# collecting info from view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table in my view containing 2 columns.
My program looks for the number of files in a folder and populates the 2nd column with the names, one in each row.
The first column contains a check box if the right column is populated.

How can I access these checkboxes and filenames in my controller after `HttpPost`?
(The number of files is not fixed, so the number of checkboxes is also not fixed)
I need to run a stored procedure afterwards if a particular file is present.

**Model**

```
public class ImportFiles
    {
        public string FileName;
        public bool FileSelected { get; set; }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ImportFiles()
    {
            string folderpath = @"C:\Users\uvaish\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\MVCDemo\MVCDemo\Models"; //path

            string filename = "*";
            string[] fileList = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(folderpath,filename);//getting the file names from the folder as an array

            List<ImportFiles> inputFiles = new List<ImportFiles>(fileList.Length);//making a list of same number of elements as the number of files            

            foreach (string str in fileList)
            {
                ImportFiles inputFile = new ImportFiles();
                inputFile.FileName = Path.GetFileName(str);
                inputFile.FileSelected = false;
                inputFiles.Add(inputFile);//creating a list of files and passing to the view
             }
            return  View  (inputFiles);
    }
```

**View**

```
<table width="550px" class="mGrid table">
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Select
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        File Name
                    </th>
                </tr>
                @foreach (ImportFiles importFiles in @Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @Html.EditorFor(importFile => @importFiles.FileSelected)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @importFiles.FileName
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
        </div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Load Selected Files" />


                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" onclick="importCancel()" value="Cancel" />
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

So , from the view I want to access the files corresponding to the checked checkboxes.
after clicking on the submit button , I should be able to manipulate the files that are selected.
I am not sure how to use the `HttpPost` method after this , could you please help?

I have enclosed the table in  view in :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LoadSelectedFiles", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
```

But I don't know how to write the `LoadSelectedFiles` controller method next, I want to access each of the ticked files now.

Comment: Can you post what you have so far please.

Comment: Model -using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyApp.Model
{
    public class ImportFiles
    {
        public string FileName;
        public bool FileSelected { get; set; }

    }
}

Comment: That comment just shows a model?  [You should edit the question to include the code that you need help with.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  The view and the controller but only the relevant parts.  Other people should be able to see what you have tried so far so that they can help you.

Comment: Try looking through other questions to see how other users have formatted their questions.  If you put the effort into writing the question you will definitely get more response.

Comment: I'll just do it , thanks!

Comment: I think a lot of your code isn't doing what you think it's doing. Start by understanding how the model binder matches names to properties, particularly in the case of collections. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ & http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: No, read the articles. You trying to do things that require a deeper understanding of the framework than you have, so it's time to start gaining that understanding, not just asking other people to write working code for you. There are lots of resources about this sort of thing and I've just pointed you in the right direction. Now it's your turn to put some effort in.

Comment: I've read the articles. But haven't got your point , may be you can suggest me some more articles ? specially for the httppost method

Comment: What specifically don't you understand how to do? If it's just "write the HTTPPost method" then, again, you need to go back to basics and start understanding the framework from the ground up. Your question is far too broad and I get the distinct feeling that you're not going to understand any answer anyone gives you because you still don't have enough knowledge of the framework. Your problem isn't simply with writing the POST method, it is with *how to produce form fields that will bind to your properties*.

Comment: okay , thanks! I'll read the links again and try to understand

Comment: The Haacked article above demonstrates exactly what you need to achieve. Read it, understand what it's doing and apply it.

Comment: okay , i got my first mistake , that I am actually not using indices while binding , so it may create a problem .But I hope you understand that I am passing a list of files as a model to my view in this case and not just the model , yeah?